# I can't pass parameters to external function to render the message, TypeError: Class constructor AlertMessage cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

whenever I try to send a message as a parameter to the showAlert() function it says:

```
TypeError: Class constructor AlertMessage cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0GGD.jpg

I just want to pass the message as a parameter and render it back to the user.
I tried to pass props directly to the AlertMessage class but it didn't work as it return an empty alert. *if my question is still unclear ask me to provide more data.*

```
   import showAlert from "../components/toast";

         ...

    export async function getStaticProps(){
      //fetch data from an API
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/posts");
      const foundData = await res.json();
          
      if(!foundData){
        return{
          notFound: true,
        }
      }
    
      if(foundData.status == 500){
         showAlert("error");
    
        return{
          notFound: true,
        }
      }else{
        return {
          props: {
            data: foundData.foundPosts
          },
          revalidate: 1 //time per seconds
        }
      }
    
    }
```

//toats .js code

```
import { Component } from "react";

export function showAlert(message){
    const myAlert = document.getElementById("myAlert");
    const alertMessage = document.getElementById("alertMessage");
    const alert = new bootstrap.Toast(myAlert);
    alertMessage.textContent = message;
    alert.show();
}

export function HideALert(){...}

export default class AlertMessage extends Component{

    render(){   
        return(
            <div className="position-fixed bottom-0 end-0 p-3" style={{zIndex: "11"}}>
                <div className="toast align-items-center text-white bg-danger border-0" id="myAlert" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
                <div className="d-flex">
                    <div className="toast-body" id="alertMessage">
                        There was an error. Please try again
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" className="btn-close btn-close-white me-2 m-auto" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the message in a round bracket like this {message},
 
and please be carful about naming your components, it would be great to name your components like this ShowAlert or Toat.js

Comment: not working, still the same

Comment: Ah, you are using class component and functional component together and it won't work like this, 

please take a look here
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/differences-between-functional-components-and-class-components-in-react/

Comment: You need to know a little bit about reactjs components

Comment: I tried to use  `<AlertMessage message="hello" />` but it return an empty this.props.message

Comment: please check the edited.

Comment: I tried your code but, I can't use bootstrap elements or `document.getElementById`  and I have to `useRef` which returns a null for `current`. I used react Component which allow me to access DOM elements.
https://imgur.com/DQSPH5F

Comment: I found out that I just messed up using document.getElemntById, since you can't really use it on React but next.js fast reload was transferring data directly to the browser which was already rendered and caused the document.getElementById() to work. and when you reload the page it executes the code and gives an error since DOM doesn't exist yet :( guess I can't use bootstrap scripts and DOM elements directly

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by passing the error on the props first.

```
  if(foundData.status == 500){ 
    return {
      props: {
        statusCode: foundData.status,
        error: foundData.status // here I pass the message I want to show
      }
    };
}
```

then checking if this error prop exists, if it does then I check if the window is defined (to know if DOM exists or not) then I show the message.

```
 if(props.error){
    if(typeof window !== "undefined"){
      showAlert(props.error);
    };
  }
```

Comment: Good, job that's cool:)